# Android intent->activity interaction

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I have
A gcm service reciever, done by-the-book.
Here's the main part

```
        //Magick. Create Intent that will show alert.
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent ma = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    Bundle b = ma.getExtras();
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("Alert_call"))
    {ma.removeExtra("Alert_call");}
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("Alert_poi"))
    {ma.removeExtra("Alert_poi");}

    ma.putExtra("Alert_call", true);
    ma.putExtra("Alert_poi", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,ma, 0);

    //Make the notification itself.
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(p.GetAlertIconFromType())
    .setContentTitle(p.GetAlertHeaderFromType())
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(p.coordsAdress + "\n" + p.ShortDesc))
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))//Do the ring
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)//Do the vibe
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)//Do the Lights blink
    .setContentText(p.coordsAdress + "\n" + p.ShortDesc);

    //Send.
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Now, at the activity side I'm catching this intent's bundle, and see if I have these "Alert_call" params. If so - use those ti show some specific info.

```
        //Magick. Create Intent that will show alert.
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent ma = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    Bundle b = ma.getExtras();
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("Alert_call"))
    {ma.removeExtra("Alert_call");}
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("Alert_poi"))
    {ma.removeExtra("Alert_poi");}

    ma.putExtra("Alert_call", true);
    ma.putExtra("Alert_poi", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,ma, 0);

    //Make the notification itself.
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(p.GetAlertIconFromType())
    .setContentTitle(p.GetAlertHeaderFromType())
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(p.coordsAdress + "\n" + p.ShortDesc))
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))//Do the ring
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)//Do the vibe
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)//Do the Lights blink
    .setContentText(p.coordsAdress + "\n" + p.ShortDesc);

    //Send.
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

-> DisplayView part

```
        //Magick. Create Intent that will show alert.
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent ma = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    Bundle b = ma.getExtras();
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("Alert_call"))
    {ma.removeExtra("Alert_call");}
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("Alert_poi"))
    {ma.removeExtra("Alert_poi");}

    ma.putExtra("Alert_call", true);
    ma.putExtra("Alert_poi", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,ma, 0);

    //Make the notification itself.
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(p.GetAlertIconFromType())
    .setContentTitle(p.GetAlertHeaderFromType())
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(p.coordsAdress + "\n" + p.ShortDesc))
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))//Do the ring
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)//Do the vibe
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)//Do the Lights blink
    .setContentText(p.coordsAdress + "\n" + p.ShortDesc);

    //Send.
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

**Now, the problem I'm facing is this:**

If I start Activity from this alert - everything works fine.
But, if I have this activity allready opened (asleep for example), and I push this Alert - I recieve null as parameters in INtent, or old ones (the ones used to start activity).

**So, the question:**

It looks like I need to get this running's activity intent, and add new data in it when I push Alert.

Is that correct? And if so - van you please guide me of where to read about it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple...

```
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,ma, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```